# How to solve error while loading model with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a flask app, and i am using tensorflow and keras to load the model that i am going to use.Below is a code snippet

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model , load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image

# Flask utils
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer

app = Flask(__name__)


Model= load_model('models/model_pro1.h5')
```

so i then deploy the flask app on heroku and it builds successfully, but when i check the logs i see that i get an error
[image for the heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I11M4.png)
I have tried installing both tensorflow and keras with out a particular version in the requirements.txt file but not getting it solved.
I want to know what i am not doing right, and thanks in advance.
I am using code from this github repo [github repo](https://github.com/npraveen092/Skin-Cancer-Detector-using-CNN)

Comment: Seems like your model was saved with some different incompatible version of Keras, incompatible to the Keras version that you use to load the model.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use same python distribution with same Keras version to save and load model? Or your model was saved by somebody else on other machine?

Comment: Also which version of Python are you using? Use at least Python 3.7. Definitely don't use Python 2.

Comment: @Arty i am using python 3.7.5 in the heroku platfrom. i defined it in the runtime.txt

Comment: @Arty the model was built from kaggle.com notebook. but that should not be a problem when using heroku

Comment: Can you provide exact link to kaggle's notebook that was used to build model? If it is public and/or non-secret.

Comment: @Arty i got the model from here [kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/sid321axn/step-wise-approach-cnn-model-77-0344-accuracy)

Comment: I just opened your kaggle link, did `Run All` cells, after complete downloaded saved `model.h5` from Data tab. Then locally on my machine did `import tensorflow as tf; tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')` and everything went fine! I have latest `tensorflow` on my machine. Maybe notebook was updated, try deleting all data/cache of these notebook and re-run it, also maybe open/copy-edit original notebook again, maybe your version is spoiled somehow. Also maybe `heroku` uses some out-dated `tensorflow` by default, there should be a way somehow to specify latest version in config.

Comment: Also try running locally same code of loading model, locally on your machine, to figure out if it is a heorku problem or model file problem.

Comment: Also you may try version of model file made by me, I just did `Run All` and downloaded `model.h5` file. I share this file by two links [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dcae649c079c979e8d201d79e4979d4a20201104065715/96f99a) or [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/7pdwml), links will be valid for around a week. Try them, they work on my Windows PC with recent `tensorflow`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an instance of saving a model and then loading it

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
model.save(./abc.h5  # saves in h5 format)
model.save(./defg)#defg is a folder having pb file
```

To load the saved model,

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./abc.h5') #for loading h5 model
```

or

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('defg/) # for loading pb model
```

I think your syntax of load_model is the mistake you committed

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with Python 3, all strings are unicode by default. So i think your dev environment, where you built and trained the models is running python2 while the heroku env has python3.